# adding jquery to firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a simple firefox addon consisting mainly from the main.js file but I need to use jquery for ajax. but I have no clue on how can I add script to my project so it could be accessible. Please help!

I found this example but still says that $ is undefined

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

contentScriptFile: data.url("jquery-1.11.2.min.js")
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete code example? If all you want to do is make an ajax request from main.js, use the [request module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I need to use jquery for ajax

No, ajax requests can actually be issued without jquery. After all jquery just provides convenience wrappers around standard browser APIs.

The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) constuctor is available in content scripts and as [net/xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr) module in the addon main.

For transforming the result into HTML, mozilla does support `xhr.responseType = "document"` which turns the response into a html document whose nodes can be inserted into the target document.

Comment: A string can be parsed with DOMParser to an HTMLDocument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 1):

Include the jquery file before other scripts file i.e. the custom javascript file. You might be including the file after your custom javascript file which uses jQuery. That's the reason `$` is `undefined`

Comment: I am no adding the main.js javasdcript file anywhere because it is run by default, so i dont hava a html to put a <script> tag in and add it before.